# Right way to check sessionStorage and pass variable to $scope in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session

I have created a token-based authentication system, but need a way for Angular to know if a user is signed in or not.

A signed in user will have there auth token in session storage. I'd like to set a variable, like `$scope.isLoggedIn = true`, if `if ( $window.sessionStorage.token )` is true.

Then I'll use `ng-if="isLoggedIn"` to show and hide elements on the page as needed. Of course, the token is authenticated before any personal info is shown. This is basically a way of showing or hiding the landing page.

I could do this in a controller, but I would have to do it in each controller. Can I do it with a factory?

Here is what I tried, but is there a better way? Thanks.

### In `app.config`:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authCheck')
```

### In `app.factory`:

```
//
// set a scope variable for whether a user is signed in or not
//
.factory('authCheck', [ '$window', '$rootScope', function ( $window, $rootScope ) {
        $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;

        if ( $window.sessionStorage.token ) {
            $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
        }

        return $rootScope.isLoggedIn;
}])
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `ng-if` to show or hide elements you don't want public. Remember, all the Angular code (in files you send to the user) is available to the client.

Comment: @trysis I know, I explained that in the post, I think. Without a valid token, they'll get nothing from the server, but they'll see a template of the page, which is fine. Although perhaps I should route to different states/templates to be more performant.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar using a service. Mine was a tad more complicated because I was getting data from indexeddb instead of localstorage (which I believe ls is synchronous rather than asynchronus.

Anyways, my code ended up being something like...

```
angular.module('App').service('DataService', ['$indexedDB', 'storeName', 'emptyCharacter', function($indexedDB, storeName, newObject){
    function function1(propertyName){
        return "something";
    };

    function function2(objects){
        return 55;
    };

    return {
        foo : function1,
        bar : function2
    };
}]);
```

And then I access it in my controller like:

```
angular.module('App').controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$interval', 'DataService', function($scope, $interval, DataService) {

    var somevar = DataService.function1();
}]);
```

As you can see, it's quite similar to what you're thinking. I think that is a perfectly fine route to take.